# How can I disable the rendering of a form input field in django form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I've got the following Form. I let Django render the form automatically for me in my template with: `{{ form.as_p() }}`. As you can see I've got the company field, however, it's redundant as I am setting the company by clean_company. The company field is hidden, but I want it to be completely gone in the template. I still need it in the form though, because I want to be able to call: `form.save(commit=True)`.

Is there a way to get the hidden field out of my template?

```
class PlantPurchaseForm(forms.ModelForm):
company = forms.CharField(initial="", widget=forms.HiddenInput())
number = forms.IntegerField(initial=10000, min_value=10000, max_value=99999)
date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={"type": "date"}))

class Meta:
    model = PlantPurchase
    fields = (
        "company",
        "number",
        "date",
        "plant",
        "costs",
    )

def __init__(self, company, *args, **kwargs):
    self.company = company
    super(PlantPurchaseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def clean_company(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data["company"]
    data = self.company
    return data

def clean_date(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data["date"]
    data = datetime.combine(data, time(hour=12))
    data = pytz.utc.localize(data)
    return data
```

The PlantPurchase Model:

```
class PlantPurchase(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name="plant_purchases")
    number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(unique=True, validators=[MinValueValidator(10000),
                                                                       MaxValueValidator(99999)])
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    plant = models.ForeignKey(Plant, related_name="plant_purchase", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    costs = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("company", "number")

    def __str__(self):
        text = "Purchase: #{} {}".format(self.number, self.plant)
        return text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by accessing the form instance in the init method. This way I could remove the company field and it won't be rendered in the template anymore.

```
class PlantPurchaseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    number = forms.IntegerField(initial=10000, min_value=10000, max_value=99999)
    date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={"type": "date"}))

    class Meta:
        model = PlantPurchase
        fields = (
            "number",
            "date",
            "plant",
            "costs",
        )

    def __init__(self, company, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PlantPurchaseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.instance.company = company

    def clean_date(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data["date"]
        data = datetime.combine(data, time(hour=12))
        data = pytz.utc.localize(data)
        return data
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways how to do it.

Basically, if you are sure that hidden field is not in use then you can remove it from the form with **exlude**. You can remove init method as well.

```
class PlantPurchaseForm(forms.ModelForm):

    number = forms.IntegerField(initial=10000, min_value=10000, max_value=99999)
    date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={"type": "date"}))

    class Meta:
        model = PlantPurchase
        fields = [
            'company',
            'number',
            'date',
            'plant',
            'costs',
        ]
        exclude = ["company"]
```

After that you need to save company into the models instance. You can either save it after form is validated:

```
def post(self, request):
    ...
    if form.is_valid():
        plantPurchase = form.save()
        plantPurchase.company = company
        plantPurchase.save()
        ...
```

..or pass the company into the save method of the form:

```
   def save(self, company, force_insert=False, force_update=False, commit=False):
        purchase = super(PlantPurchaseForm, self).save(commit=commit)
        purchase.company = company
        purchase.save()
        return purchase
```

Comment: I feel like writing code to save the company field, after the form is validated, is redundant. Because I already have access to the company in the form. I was wondering if there is a way to not render this field and set the value in the init method of the form. But I couldn't find out if that's even possible.